# POST request failed from Postman to Jdoodle API

Tags: api, post, postman, jdoodle

I have created an account on jdoodle and buy a free plan in which we can make 200 requests per days and from there I got credentials (clientId and clientSecret) for making request to their api .

I am making post request from postman to Jdoodle api. It is giving me response as unauthorized request with status code 401 in spite of valid credentials.
Giving me unauthorised request error also when i make request for checking credits used or (how many calls I have made to their api).

POST- https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/

```
{
    "clientID" : "83xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "clientSecret" : "30xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "script" : "console.log('hello')", 
    "language" : "nodejs", 
    "versionIndex" : "0"
}
```

Response I am getting is -

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized Request",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

POST- https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/credit-spent

```
{
    "clientID" : "83xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "clientSecret" : "30xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
}
```

Response I am getting is -

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized Request",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

I don't know why I am getting such response inspite of all valid credentials and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this postman collection. Mostly it looks like your issue is with auth. make sure if client_id and secret are safely substituted.

```json
{
    "auth": null,
    "event": null,
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": null,
        "description": null,
        "name": "JDoodle Compiler API.http",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "version": null
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "description": null,
            "event": null,
            "id": null,
            "name": "Execute Program",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": null,
            "request": {
                "auth": null,
                "body": {
                    "disabled": null,
                    "file": null,
                    "formdata": null,
                    "graphql": null,
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "options": {
                        "language": "json"
                    },
                    "raw": "{\"clientId\": \"{{clientId}}\", \"clientSecret\": \"{{clientSecret}}\", \"script\": \"print 'hello'\", \"language\": \"python2\", \"versionIndex\": \"0\"}",
                    "urlencoded": null
                },
                "certificate": null,
                "description": "Execute Program",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "key": "content-type",
                        "value": "application/json"
                    }
                ],
                "method": "POST",
                "proxy": null,
                "url": "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/"
            },
            "response": null,
            "variable": null,
            "auth": null,
            "item": null
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": null,
    "variable": [
        {
            "description": null,
            "disabled": false,
            "id": null,
            "key": "baseUrl",
            "name": null,
            "system": null,
            "type": null,
            "value": "httpsDefaultParameterValue:DefaultParameterValue@DefaultParameterValue.myshopify.com/"
        },
        {
            "description": null,
            "disabled": false,
            "id": null,
            "key": "id",
            "name": null,
            "system": null,
            "type": null,
            "value": "<post>"
        },
        {
            "description": null,
            "disabled": false,
            "id": null,
            "key": "event_id",
            "name": null,
            "system": null,
            "type": null,
            "value": "<>"
        }
    ]
}
```

With [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) request is far simple and easily sharable

```http
@name("Execute Program")
POST "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/"
json({
    "clientId": "{{clientId}}",
    "clientSecret": "{{clientSecret}}",
    // "script": '<?php echo "hello"; ?>',
    // "language": "php",
    "script" :"print 'hello'",
    "language": "python2",
    // "stdin": "",
    "versionIndex": "0"
})
```